# Homeomorphisms between any two doubly punctured spheres and two punctured $R^n$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

Let $p, q$ be the north pole and the south pole of $S^n$ respectively.

Then $S^n-p-q$ is homeomorphic to $S^n-a-b$ where $a,b$, are distinct points in $S^n$.

Also $R^n-a$ is homeomorphic to $R^n-b$, where $a\neq b$.

What are examples of such homeomorphisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've seen the homeomorphism between the punctured sphere and $R^n$, then this shouldn't be too bad. (Search "Riemann sphere" for a simple explicit construction.) Call such a homeomorphism $f$.

You can use $f$ to map $S^n - p$ to $R^n$. If we remove the origin from both, the homeomorphism still holds, so $S^n - p - q \cong R^n - 0$. Then because translation $T$ is a homeomorphism in $R^n$, we can map $R^n - 0$ to $R^n - T(0)$. Then this can be imaged back with $f^{-1}$ to $S^n - p - T(0)$ Finally a rotation $\mathcal{R}$ can turn $S^n - p - T(0)$ into $S^n - \mathcal{R}(p) - \mathcal{R}(T(0))$.

By choosing $T$ and $\mathcal{R}$ appropriately, we can make $p'$ and $T(0)$ be whatever we want. (Choose $T$ to place the two points the appropriate distance from each other, and $\mathcal{R}$ to give the correct absolute angle.) Thus any $S^n - a - b$ is homeomorphic to to any $S^n - p - q$. We used the equivalence of $R^n - a$ and $R^n - b$ along the way, since translation is alright.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to exhibit a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ which sends $a$ to $b$.  For this, a translation by $b-a$ would be the easiest example.

For $S^n$: first imagine first rotating from the north pole $p$ to any point $a$.  Now stereographically project, $f: S^n - \left\{ a \right\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$.  Now you can translate $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $f(b) - f(q)$ and inverse project.